# Finding Points with Same Distance to two Lines

Tags: geometry

I know this is quite a basic question but I just don't seem to get the correct solution.

Given are the two lines:

$g: \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} + t*\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $

$h: \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} + t*\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} $

The task is to find all the points with the same distance to these two straight lines.
Well in my opinion these would be all the points on the planes on the bisection of the two straight lines. 
If we want to write the equation for these planes we first need a point which is obviously given by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and a normalvector. For the normalvector I would first normalize the vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$, add them up, divide throug 2 and then calculate the distance from $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ to this point but that doesn't give me the correct answer...what would the correct approach be?

Comment: The locus are the two angle bisectors of the two lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of two lines in a plane, the points equidistant from the lines are on both bisectors of the angles formed by the lines.  In space, you can then add any vector perpendicular to the plane the lines are in to those bisectors.

Your approach is sound, but it seems you forgot to add the resulting vector to $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$.

If we normalize $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ we get $\begin{pmatrix} 2/3 \\ 2/3 \\ 1/3 \end{pmatrix}$ and if we normalize $\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$ we get $\begin{pmatrix} 6/7 \\ 2/7 \\ 3/7 \end{pmatrix}$, so one bisector line is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}+r\left( \begin{pmatrix} 2/3 \\ 2/3 \\ 1/3 \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} 6/7 \\ 2/7 \\ 3/7 \end{pmatrix}\right)$ and the other is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}+u\left( \begin{pmatrix} 2/3 \\ 2/3 \\ 1/3 \end{pmatrix}- \begin{pmatrix} 6/7 \\ 2/7 \\ 3/7 \end{pmatrix}\right)$.  Now add to each of these a vector perpendicular to the plane and you are done.

Comment: alright, but the perpendicular vector to add, wouldn't it e.g. be (1,-1,2) - ((2/3,2/3,1/3)+(6/7,2/7,3/7))?

Comment: @servette:  no, I would get it from the cross product of the two direction vectors.  It would be $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$ because both of those vectors are in the plane.

Comment: ok, so for the vectorproduct I get (4,0,-8) and for the bisector lines accordingly (1,-1,2)+r(116/21,20/21,-152/21) or (1,-1,2)+r(80/21,8/21,-170/21) respectively. Is this correct?

Comment: @servette:  I agree with the cross product.  But we are trying to make planes.  We have the bisector lines in my answer.  One plane would be $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}+r\left( \begin{pmatrix} 2/3 \\ 2/3 \\ 1/3 \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} 6/7 \\ 2/7 \\ 3/7 \end{pmatrix}\right)+s\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 0 \\ -8 \end{pmatrix}$.  With the two parameters, you have a two dimensional object-a plane.  The other has a minus sign that comes from the other line.

Comment: of course..I see, thanks!